# Failing test from Easy Active Record Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I get a failing test as I go through the tutorial: Easy Active Record for Rails Developers by Jason Gilmore.

For some context, the tutorial instructs me to generate a Location model. The results are below:

```
rails generate model Location name:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20140724130112_create_locations.rb
  create    app/models/location.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/location_spec.rb
  invoke      factory_girl
  create       spec/factories/locations.rb
```

In the section "*Defining fixtures using FactoryGirl*", Gilmore wants to show how FactoryGirl provides a facility for generating model factories. To do this, I am instructed to open up spec/factories/locations.rb and to expect to see:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :location do
    name "MyString"
  end
end
```

and after that to modify the file above to look like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :location do 
    name 'Pizza Works'
  end 
end
```

Then I am told to save the file i.e. locations.rb and to return to the Location spec (spec/models/**location.rb**) and to add the following test:

```
it "can be created using a factory" do 
  location = FactoryGirl.build(:location) 
  expect(location).to eq('Pizza Works')
end
```

The first problem is that there is no such file i.e. (spec/models/**location.rb**) does not exist. The closest file to that file in the spec folder is (spec/models/**location_spec.rb**).

So guessing it was a typo, I added the the above test to (spec/models/**location_spec.rb**) instead.

*My first question is did I miss a location.rb file somehow? Or is this a typo on Gilmore's part?*

Second, after running the test using

```
rspec -fd spec/models/location_spec.rb
```

The tutorial says I should get the following results

```
Location
  can be instantiated
  has a valid factory
  can be assigned the name of an arcade

Finished in 0.04053 seconds (files took 2.05 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
```

But what I get instead is

```
Location
  can be instantiated
  can be assigned the name of an arcade
  can be created using a factory (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Location can be created using a factory
     Failure/Error: expect(location).to eq('Pizza Works')

       expected: "Pizza Works"
            got: #<Location id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: "Pizza Works", description: nil>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,7 @@
       -"Pizza Works"
       +#<Location:0x007fcf66060850
       + id: nil,
       + created_at: nil,
       + updated_at: nil,
       + name: "Pizza Works",
       + description: nil>

     # ./spec/models/location_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05663 seconds (files took 3.26 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure
```

*So my second question is, why is my test failing and what should I do to fix it?*

Any help is great appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the location name to be 'Pizza Works'. Not the object 'location' it self.

Update this code:

```
it "can be created using a factory" do 
  location = FactoryGirl.build(:location) 
  expect(location.name).to eq('Pizza Works')
end
```

Comment: Fantastic! I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

That's a error in the Spec. The test should be

```
expect(location.name).to eq('Pizza Works')
```